# Property is not acting according to the specification

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time understanding why the behavior of certain properties do not follow the behavior stated in the W3 specification.

For example, in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) it says that the "background-image" and "background-color" property is not inherited.

But the following code proves this otherwise.

The CSS

```
#nav > li {
    background-color: yellow;}
```

The markup

```
<div>
  <ul id="nav">
   <li>This is a list</li>
   <li>This is a list</li>
   <li>
    <ul>
     <li>This is a list</li>
     <li>This is a list</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You will see that even the 2nd level list items which is nested inside the 3rd list item also has their background-color changed, while I only intended for it to be applied only on the direct children which is the 1st level list items.

Now my question is this.

Why is this happening? Who is in the wrong here, the browsers or the specification? Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you know that you have to accept the right answers, or?!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your answer.
When you look at the devtools, you will see, that the 2nd level got no background-color. The color you see, is the color of the parent li :-)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2brhj2bq/)

```
#nav > li {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

With the border property you can see it better.
Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2brhj2bq/1/

```
#nav li {
    border:1px solid red; 
}

#nav > li {
    border:1px solid lime;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that even though the 2nd level list items are styled, it's actually the 1st level list item that is styling them?

Comment: The second level items have no bg-color, so what you see is the color of the first level item.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the next UL is also in the Li , and li have bg color yellow so it should be yellow . just think it what have you done , you are assigning bg then you are seeking why it is happening it is not the bg of inner ul li it is the bg of ul#nav li.

Comment: I see, so the 1st level list item is styling them?

Comment: There is now style for second level li's , it is style of first level Li's.

Comment: Set the second level li's bg green you will see there is no effect of first level li's on them